# Fourier transform of $-x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

How do I compute the Fourier transform of $-x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$?

I don't think I can just split this apart and say $\mathscr{F}(-x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2})=\mathscr{F}(-x^2)\cdot\mathscr{F}(e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2})$. That seems too easy, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you can use the following property $\mathscr{F}[x^nf(x)] = \Big(\frac{i}{2\pi}\Big)^n \frac{d^n}{d t^n}\mathscr{F}[f](t)$. But mind definition of Fourier transform in your class, $\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi}\Big)^n$ can disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: there's a formula for the Fourier transform of a derivative.

Answer (score 0):

${\cal F}[f(x)] = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{2 \pi i t x} dx$.

${\cal F}[-x^2 e^{-x^2/2}] = (t^2 -1)e^{-t^2/2}$.

Comment: Could you explain how you did this?  I have that $$\mathscr{F}(-x^2e^{-x^2/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega x}(-x^2e^{-x^2/2}dx$$ and I'm having a hard time solving this.

Comment: The question was "How do I compute the Fourier transform." Your response does not answer that. Please explain how you got that result.